# Picard Condition (searching for an idea)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

The so-called Picard-condition is:

Let X,Y be Hilbertspaces and $T\colon X\to Y$ is a compact operator with singular value decomposition system $\left\{(\sigma_j,u_j,v_j)\right\}$. An element $x\in\overline{\operatorname{range}(T)}$ is an element in $\operatorname{range}(T)$ exactly then when 
$$
\sum\limits_j^{\infty}\frac{\lvert\langle x,v_j\rangle\rvert^2}{\sigma_j^2}<\infty.
$$

Task: Show that from the Picard-condition it follows that 
$$
\operatorname{range}(T)\neq\overline{\operatorname{range}(T)}.
$$

---

Let $x\in \overline{\operatorname{range}(T)}$. When $\sum\limits_j^{\infty}\frac{\lvert\langle x,v_j\rangle\rvert^2}{\sigma_j^2}$ is not smaller than $\infty$, then it follows that $x\notin\operatorname{range}(T)$ and so automatically $\operatorname{range}(T)\neq\overline{\operatorname{range}(T)}.$.

So assume that $\sum\limits_j^{\infty}\frac{\lvert\langle x,v_j\rangle\rvert^2}{\sigma_j^2}<\infty$. Let again $x\in \overline{\operatorname{range}(T)}$, then it follows from the Picard-condition, that $x\in\operatorname{range}(T)$, which means $\overline{\operatorname{range}(T)}\subseteq\operatorname{range}(T)$

Now I have to show that it is not the other way round, which means I have to show that $x\in \operatorname{range}(T)\nrightarrow x\in\overline{\operatorname{range}(T)}$? If yes, how can I show that?

Or what Di I have to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only finitely many $\sigma_j$ are nonzero, the result is not true: in that case, the range of $T$ is finite-dimensional, and so $\mbox{range}(T)=\overline{\mbox{range}(T)}$.

When infinitely many $\sigma_j$ are nonzero (i.e. when $T$ is not of finite rank), we always have the proper inclusion 
$$
\mbox{range}(T)\subsetneq\overline{\mbox{range}(T)}.
$$
To see this, note that since $\sigma_j\to0$, we can choose a subsequence $\sigma_{j_k}$ such that $\sigma_{j_k}<1/k^2$. Now, for each $k$,
$$
v_{j_k}=T\left(\frac1{\sigma_{j_k}}\,u_{j_k}\right)\in\mbox{range}(T).
$$
Consider 
$$
x=\sum_k\sigma_{j_k}v_{j_k}\in Y
$$
(this is well-defined since $\sum_k\sigma_{j_k}^2<\sum_k\frac1{k^2}<\infty$).
Then $x\in\overline{\mbox{range}(T)}$, as the partial sums in the series belong to $\mbox{range}(T)$ (since it is a subspace that contains the $v_{j_k}$). On the other hand,
$$
\sum_j\frac{|\langle x,v_j\rangle|^2}{\sigma_j^2}\geq\sum_k\frac{|\langle x,v_{j_k}\rangle|^2}{\sigma_{j_k}^2}=\sum_k\frac{\sigma_{j_k}^2}{\sigma_{j_k}^2}=\infty,
$$
so $x\not\in\mbox{range}(T)$

Comment: I do not understand why one can choose x this way.

Comment: Is this a special x ? Construated to show that there is an element that is in $\overline{range(T)}$, but not in $range(T)$? And another thing:  I dont see why always $range(T)\varsubsetneq \overline{range(T)}$.

Comment: The $x$ can be constructed because in any Hilbert space, every time you have an orthonormal sequence $\{e_k\}$ and an $\ell^2$-sequence $\{c_k\}$ one can define the vector $\sum_kc_ke_k$.

Comment: The $x$ constructed satisfies $x\in\overline{\mbox{range}(T)}$ because it is a limit of linear combinations of elements in $\mbox{range}(T)$. And it is not in $\mbox{range}(T)$ by the Picard criterion. As this construction can be done for any choice of $\{\sigma_j\}$ (provided that infinitely many are nonzero) and orthonormal sets $\{u_j\}$ and $\{v_j\}$, it shows that the inclusion is proper every time that $T$ is not of finite rank.

Comment: Thank you. Last question: When only finetely many $\sigma_j$ are nonzero: Why is the range of T then finite dimensionak and why follows from this that $rang(T)=\overline{rang(T)}$?

Comment: Suppose for simplicity that $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n$ are nonzero and the rest are zero. Then $\mbox{range}(T)=\mbox{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$. As it is a finite-dimensional vector space it is closed, and so it agrees with its closure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: One more question, sorry: $\left\{v_j\right\}$ is an Orthonormalbasis of $\overline{\mbox{range}(T)}$, right? And $\sigma_j\to 0$. Is it right that then $x=\sum\limits_j \sigma_jv_j$ is an element of $\overline{\mbox{range}(T)}$ and if yes, why not using THIS element x for the proof?

Comment: That's not good enough. Say $\sigma_j=1/\sqrt j$. Then your $x$ doesn't exist (the coefficients of a vector in a Hilbert space, expressed in an orthonormal basis, are square-summable).

Comment: I still do not understand why the construction of your x. Is there a sentece of something that says that for orthogonalsystems and sequences that tend to 0? Is there such an sentence for orthonormalbasis and null-sequnce, too?

Comment: I don't understand your question. In my answer, I choose a subsequence of the $\sigma_j$ precisely to have an $\ell^2$-sequence so that the definition of $x$ does make sense.

Comment: My question concerns the construction of x... i never heard, that one can construct an element out of any $\ell^2$ - sequence and an orthonormal system. Is there a sentence which says that? And can one construct an element x out of a $\ell^2$ - sequence and an orthonormalbasis, too? I am just searching the origin of your construction of x - because this is an idea I would never had alone.

Comment: I would say that it is the most basic fact about infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces: Parseval's identity tells you that the coefficients of vectors expressed in a given orthonormal basis are precisely the $\ell^2$-sequences.

Comment: i have a vector x in $\overline{\mbox{range}(T)}$. then i can write this as $x=\sum_j \langle x,v_j\rangle v_j$. right? and parseval says $\lVert x\rVert^2=\sum\limits_j\lvert\langle x,v_j\rangle\rvert^2$. And now? Sorry when disturbing you.

Comment: Yes, but the point here is the opposite. I want to construct a vector with certain properties of its coefficients: namely, they have to be $\ell^2$ so that I obtain an actual vector, and I also want them to fail Picard's criterion. The obvious choice to fail Picard's criterion is to use $\sigma_j$ as the coefficients; but they might not be $\ell^2$; so I choose a subsequence that is $\ell^2$.

Comment: what do you mean with coefficients of vectors expressed in a given orthonormal basis? why are they $\ell^2$? what do you mean whith coefficnents?? i do not know that..

Comment: Sorry. All what you are saying and using is; When H is a Hilberspace with orthonormal basis $S$, then $H\cong \ell^2(S)$ - right? And here $H=\overline{\mbox{range}(T)}$ and $S=\left\{v_j\right\}$ - right? But in the third comment you said this for orthonormalsystems and not for orthonormalbasis - was that right?

Comment: Yes. Please read the proof. Since I'm taking a subsequence of the $v_j$, it is obviously not an orthonormal basis. But that's irrelevant. Given any orthonormal system, it is an orthonormal basis of its own closed linear span.

Comment: So $S:=\left\{v_{j_k}\right\}$ is orthonormal basis of the Hilbert space $\overline{\mbox{span}\left\{v_{j_k}\right\}}$. Then one can use that $\overline{\mbox{span}\left\{v_{j_k}\right\}}\equiv \ell^2(S)$ and so $x=\sum\limits_{k\geq 1}c_kv_{j_k}\in\overline{\mbox{span}\left\{v_{j_k}\right\}}\subseteq \overline{\mbox{range}(T)}$. And as the $c_k$ one can use the special chosen $\sigma_{j_k}$ which are $\ell^2(S)$. Is that right now? And then the other argumentation with the Picard criterion follows.

Comment: Yes.${\ \ \ \ }$

Comment: Okay, again: THANK YOU VERY MUCH i learned A LOT

Comment: Maybe you have an tip for me concerning this question that is (i think so) linked to this question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281365/picard-criterion-show-mboxranget-bot-overline-mboxranget-bot

Comment: I have written an answer to that question.