# Picard criterion: Show $\mbox{range}(T)^{\bot}=\overline{\mbox{range}(T)}^{\bot}$

Tags: operator-theory

The so-called Picard criterion is:

Let X,Y be Hilbertspaces and $T\colon X\to Y$ is a compact operator with singular value decomposition system $\left\{(\sigma_j,u_j,v_j)\right\}$. An element $x\in\overline{\operatorname{range}(T)}$ is an element in $\operatorname{range}(T)$ exactly then when 
$$
\sum\limits_j^{\infty}\frac{\lvert\langle x,v_j\rangle\rvert^2}{\sigma_j^2}<\infty.
$$

Task: Show that
$$
\mbox{range}(T)^{\bot}=\overline{\mbox{range}(T)}^{\bot}.
$$

---

Unfortunately I do not have any idea yet.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Picard's criterion nor with compact operators. It is a general fact in Hilbert spaces that given a subset $K\subset H$ (it doesn't even have to a subspace), then 
$$
K^\perp=\overline{K}^\perp.
$$
Indeed, since $K\subset \overline K$, then $\overline K^\perp\subset K^\perp$ (i.e. any vector that is orthogonal to all vectors in $\overline K$ is orthogonal to all vectors in $K$). To see the reverse inclusion, suppose that $y\in K^\perp$, and let $x\in\overline K$. This means that $x=\lim x_n$ for vectors $x_n\in K$. Then
$$
\langle y,x\rangle=\lim_n\;\langle y,x_n\rangle=\lim_n\; 0=0.
$$
As $x$ was any elements of $\overline K$, we conclude that $y\in\overline K^\perp$. So $K^\perp\subset\overline K^\perp$. Together with the previous inclusion, this guarantees that $\overline K^\perp=K^\perp$.

Comment: It will take some time to understand. Then I will surely ask something. By now: Thank you very much!!

Comment: Why is $\langle y,\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n\rangle=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\langle y,x_n\rangle$?

Comment: Because the inner product is continuous. You can obtain this directly from Cauchy-Schwarz: $$|\langle y,x-x_n\rangle|\leq\|y\|\,\|x-x_n\|.$$

Comment: Yes, I remember that it is continious in both components... arrr.. thank you for remembering me..